# Order of hoisting in Javascript detailed

Tags: javascript, hoisting, hoist

Question #1.

I understand that "var" is function scoped, but does javascript order the hoist alphabetically? or first come first serve.

```
function x () {
    var b;
    var c;
    var a;
}
```

After hoisting, does the result become this or the same result as above:

```
function x() {
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;
}
```

Question #2.

I understand that function is hoisted before variables.

When I run this:

```js
function x() {
  var b = 2;
  var c = 3;
  var a = 1;

  function y() {
    var d = 4;
  }
}

console.log(x);
```

I don't see the "function y()" being printed before the vars.

Comment: Hoisting does not have an order, since it isn't observable at language-level.

Answer (score 4):

The order in which the variable names are "created" when hoisted doesn't matter, because just creating a variable name (possibly in addition to creating a function tied to the variable name, in the case of a function declaration) *doesn't affect anything else*. Nothing involved in it has any side effects, so the order in which the interpreter actually creates the variable names is opaque and irrelevant. That's a good thing - it means you don't have to worry about it.

That's assuming you're wondering about how things work at *runtime*, and don't have any syntax errors. If you *do* have syntax errors and are declaring variables with `const` or `let`, duplicate variable declarations for the same variable name in the same scope are forbidden, so the first duplicate identifier (in the same order as in the source code) will throw a syntax error.

```js
let foo;

function foo() { // <-- This line throws
}
```

> I don't see the "function y()" being printed before the vars.

When you do

```
console.log(x);
```

where `x` is a function, you'll just be given the function *source code*, which will be exactly as you typed it in the script - the code isn't altered in any way, so any "hoisting" effects won't be visible.